# Code execution before data is received. How to fix it?

Tags: node.js, function, socket.io, nan, execution

I recently started learning javascript and ran into a code execution problem at the wrong moment.
When creating a calculator, I managed to write this code.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(serv,{});
var b
var a
var c
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('new connection!');
    socket.on('clntMsg',function(data){
        b = eval(data);
        console.log(data);
    });
    
    socket.on('clntMsg2',function(data){
        c = eval(data);
        console.log(data);
        a = b / c
        console.log(a);
            socket.emit('serverMsg',{
                msg:(a),
            });
        });

    });
```

This code works great, but as soon as I moved the computational part outside of the function,

```
a = b / c;
```

so I can apply it elsewhere in the code. And when I moved the emit

```
    socket.emit('serverMsg',{
        msg:(a),
    });
```

so that this function does not only belong to "clntMsg2". And it functioned for all functions.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(serv,{});
var b
var a
var c
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('new connection!');
    socket.on('clntMsg',function(data){
        b = eval(data);
        console.log(data);
    });
    
    socket.on('clntMsg2',function(data){
        c = eval(data);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(a);
    });
    socket.emit('serverMsg',{
        msg:(a),
    });

});
    a = b / c;
```

And after that "null" is displayed in the results of calculations, and the calculation itself begins even before receiving 'clntMsg'. Tell me how to tell the code when it should perform the calculation.

Comment: Be advised that your code is terribly unsafe due to these use of `eval` on user-supplied data.

Comment: AKX, i used type = "number" in the client part

Comment: and it is also a learning material

Comment: A `type="number"` input doesn't prevent an attacker from just posting a malicious request. Also, for learning material, you should learn to make things secure.

Comment: AKX,I know that me need to add debug, so if the received data is not a number, then the server did not crash, but stopped calculating unnecessary information. I understand all this, it would be better if you answered the question that I asked above, since without solving it, I will not be able to advance further